How to fix listening Speech Recognition didn't work properly, somehow make the cursor paused or slower?
I use gesture recognition mediapipe and wanted to mix with `listen_in_background` function ceased to function after code modifications. The cursor movement has become slow and laggy, with pauses occurring when Speech Recognition is activated.
def callback(recognizer, audio):
    try:
        print(recognizer.recognize_google(audio))
        text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language = "id")
        if "Tuliskan" in text.lower():
            speak("Silahkan Bicara!")
            teks = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language = "id")
            pyautogui.write(teks)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        pass

def main():
    recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
    mic = sr.Microphone(0)
    with mic as source:
        recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    stop_listening = recognizer.listen_in_background(mic, callback)
    stop_listening(wait_for_stop=True)

    while True:  
            pTime = 0               # Digunakan untuk menghitung frame rate
            width = 320             # Lebar Kamera
            height = 240            # Tinggi Kamera
            frameR = 60            # Frame Rate
            smoothening = 8         # Faktor Pelancaran
            prev_x, prev_y = 0, 0   # Koordinat Sebelumnya
            curr_x, curr_y = 0, 0   # Koordinat Saat Ini

            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)   # Mendapatkan feed video dari webcam
            cap.set(3, width)           # Menyesuaikan ukuran
            cap.set(4, height)

            detector = ht.handDetector(maxHands=1)                  # Mendeteksi satu tangan maksimal
            screen_width, screen_height = pyautogui.size()          # Mendapatkan ukuran layar
            
            while True:
                success, img = cap.read()
                img = detector.findHands(img)                       # Mencari tangan
                lmlist, bbox = detector.findPosition(img)           # Mendapatkan posisi tangan

                if len(lmlist)!=0:
                    x1, y1 = lmlist[8][1:]
                    x2, y2 = lmlist[12][1:]

                    fingers = detector.fingersUp()
                    cv2.rectangle(img, (frameR, frameR), (width - frameR, height - frameR), (255, 0, 255), 2)
                    if  fingers[1] == 1 and fingers[2] == 0:
                        x3 = np.interp(x1, (frameR,width-frameR), (0,screen_width))
                        y3 = np.interp(y1, (frameR, height-frameR), (0, screen_height))

                        curr_x = prev_x + (x3 - prev_x) / smoothening
                        curr_y = prev_y + (y3 - prev_y) / smoothening

                        pyautogui.moveTo(screen_width - curr_x, curr_y) 
                        cv2.circle(img, (x1, y1), 7, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
                        prev_x, prev_y = curr_x, curr_y

                    if fingers[0] == 1 and fingers[1] == 1:
                        length, img, lineInfo = detector.findDistance(4, 6, img)
                        print(length)
                        if length < 30:
                            cv2.circle(img, (lineInfo[4], lineInfo[5]), 15, (0, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)
                            pyautogui.click()    # Melakukan Klik

                    if fingers[1] == 1 and (fingers[0] == 0 and fingers[4] == 1):
                        pyautogui.scroll(100)

                    if fingers[1] == 1 and (fingers[0] == 1 and fingers[4] == 1):
                        pyautogui.scroll(-100)

                cTime = time.time()
                fps = 1/(cTime-pTime)
                pTime = cTime
                cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (20, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, (255, 0, 0), 3)
                cv2.imshow("Image", img)
                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break

            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I've encountered performance issues after integrating gesture recognition with the listen_in_background function for speech recognition. As a result, cursor movement has become sluggish and pauses occur during speech recognition activation. Help me to fix this code! Thanks.
